# How do I open a Link in in inApp browser with an expression value?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a dynamic link to an href in Angular/Ionic but the below is not working. I had an "onclick before the ng-click" as the expression {{post.id}} was not loading.

```
 <a class="w-inline-block post-block-link" href="" ng-click="window.open('http://www.example.com/#/post/{{post.id}}', '_blank', 'location=no'); return false;" data-ix="press" ng-repeat="post in postList">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="openWindow(post)" ng-repeat="post in postList"></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
yourApp.controller('yourController', function($scope) {
    $scope.openWindow = function(post) {
        var url = 'http://www.example.com/#/post/' + post.id;
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. Each post has its own id which i need to translate at the end of the url...

Comment: You may construct your URL as you wish. Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Huge help. Thanks @RuslanasBalčiūnas